# What's making this code lock my aiosqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py, aiosqlite

My discord.py bot handles data inputs (invites, bans, warns, etc.) and inserts them into an aiosqlite database. An error is raised:

> OperationalError: database is locked.

Multiple commands work in unison to handle warnings and such. When I invoke my warning system, it locks my database:

```
@commands.command()
async def warn(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *,
               reason: str = 'No reason provided.'):
    await self.addwarn(ctx, member, reason=reason) # Add a warning


@commands.command()
async def addwarn(self, ctx, member, *, reason):

    self.bot.db = await aiosqlite.connect("database.db") # Connect to db

    async with self.bot.db.cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Warns "
                             "(User, Reason, Time, Server) VALUES "
                             "(?,?,?,?)",
                             (member.id, reason,
                             int(datetime.now().timestamp()),
                             member.guild.id)) # Register the warning's reason, member id, time, and guild id

    async with self.bot.db.cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.execute('SELECT Reason, Time FROM Warns WHERE '
                             'User = ? AND Server = ?',
                             (member.id, member.guild.id)) # Fetch past warning records from db

        data = await cursor.fetchall() # Store past records in a variable
        if data:
            warnnum = 0 # Warning count

            for record in data:
                warnnum += 1 # Increment variable for past records in db

            if warnnum >= 3: # If user has 3 warnings, ban them
                await self.ban_member(ctx, member=member,
                                      reason='User has exceeded their '
                                      'warnings limit, and has been '
                                      'banned as a result.')

            if member.joined_at >= datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(hours=3): # If user has joined within the
                                                                                    # past 3 hours prior to receiving
                                                                                    # a warning, ban them
                await self.ban_member(ctx, member=member,
                                      reason='User has gained an '
                                      'infraction within a short duration '
                                      'of joining.')
    await self.bot.db.commit() # Commit the changes


@commands.command()
async def ban_member(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):

    await member.ban(reason=reason) # Ban the member

    await self.clearwarn(ctx, member) # Clear a member's entire warning record when they're banned


async def clearwarn(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    self.bot.db = await aiosqlite.connect("database.db")

    async with self.bot.db.cursor() as cursor:
        await cursor.execute('DELETE FROM Warns WHERE User = ? '
                             'AND Server = ?',
                             (member.id, ctx.guild.id)) # Clear a member's entire warning record
    await self.bot.db.commit()
```

What's making this code lock my aiosqlite database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite is meant to be a lightweight database, and thus can't support a high level of concurrency. `OperationalError: database is locked` errors indicate that your application is experiencing more concurrency than SQLite can handle in default configuration. This error means that one thread or process has an exclusive lock on the database connection and another thread timed out waiting for the lock to be released.

Python's SQLite wrapper has a default timeout value that determines how long the second thread is allowed to wait on the lock before it times out and raises the `OperationalError: database is locked error`.

**Ways to solve this error**

- Switching to another database backend. At a certain point, SQLite becomes too "lite" for real-world applications, and these sorts of concurrency errors indicate you've reached that point.
- Increase the default timeout value by setting the timeout database option
- Rewriting your code to reduce concurrency and ensure that database transactions are short-lived.

Comment: Thing is, I'm using aiosqlite - not SQLite; it doesn't have a timeout parameter for connections (as far as I'm aware) - since it's asynchronous and has a context manager for these nuances.

Comment: @Angel After doing some research, there is no possible to way to solve this problem other than switching your library to use other SQL databases that can handle concurrency

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I managed to miraculously fix this issue without switching to a new database; here's how:

First thing was that the main issue here was all those `self.bot.db = await aiosqlite.connect("database.db")` connections lying around within each function; they were the main reason the database was being locked - since each one of them created a brand new connection instance (my call stack sometimes registered straight up 20+ threads, excluding the main thread and the asyncio_0 thread; it was hurrendous); so, I fixed it by doing this:

Within main.py:

```
# At the top of the code:
bot = commands.Bot(...)
bot.db_con = None # A global variable, which assigns 
                  # a connection to the entire bot, 
                  # and is reusable within Cogs

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    if bot.db_con is None:
        bot.db_con = bot.db_con = await aiosqlite.connect("database.db")
    ...

# Rest of code
```

Within Cogs:

```
class ClassName(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.bot = bot
        self.bot.db_con = bot.db_con
        ...

    # Rest of code
```

Now, my class stack at most registers 5 threads at once (including the main thread and the asyncio_0 thread); this is because the ENTIRE bot now only uses a single connection.

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles upon this question, and I hope you have a great day :)